# Python, define global variable in a class and import this class for main script,but that global variable is not defined

Tags: python, class, import, global-variables

I have a basic.py file under a specific folder which defined a class:

```
class test_function:
    def loop_unit(self,str):
        global test_list
        test_list.append(str)
```

I have another main.py which have following code

```
from folder import basic
test_list=[]
object=basic.test_function()
object.loop_unit('teststr')
print(test_list)
```

it will give an error says

name 'test_list' is not defined(it trackback to test_list.append(str) )
I actually defined global variable in the function, and I defined it at the start of the main code, why it still said this is not defined?

Comment: Globals belong to the module in which they are defined.

Comment: can you explain it a little bit? thank you

Comment: "Global" is a bit of a misnomer; it should have been called "module-local" or similar. The only truly global namespace is the built-in namespace, which you cannot add to. Global variables always refer to variables in the module in which the function is *defined*, not where it is *called*.

Comment: @chepner you can, unfortunately, add to the built-in namespace

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Reliably? I know you can add attributes to the `builtins` module, but I thought that was akin to modifying the `dict` returned by `vars()` to modify a local scope.

Comment: @chepner nope, it works

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't be modifying that global variable anyway. and note, `global test_list ` is useless and can be removed

Comment: OK, here's the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#builtins-and-restricted-execution) that directs the user to use the `builtins` module to modify the scope. `__builtins__` is the implementation detail (more convenient because it itself is in the built-in scope, when it exists at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `main.test_list`; `test_function.loop_unit` wants `basic.test_list`.

```
from folder import basic
basic.test_list = []
object = basic.test_function()
object.loop_unit('teststr')
print(basic.test_list)
```

Comment: sorry I did not make this clear, actually folder is just where this basic saved, you can check what I edit to the example, it should be more clear

Comment: I think I got what you mean here, global variable is belong to the module, thank you ! it works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this in your class definition:

```py
class test_function:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_list = []

    def loop_unit(self,str):
        sel.test_list.append(str)
```

```py
from folder import basic
#test_list=[]  --remove this line
object=basic.test_function()
object.loop_unit('teststr')
#print(test_list) ---remove this line but add this:
print(object.test_list)
```

Try and tell me if it works.

Comment: I can not do in this way, becuase test_list will be continuously changes in main script, just like you see the name is loop_unit, it will run for several unit